# How to make org-babel-load-file use umlauts (åäö) correctly?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have this in my init.el

```
(defvar dropbox-d "C:/Dropbox")
(defvar dropbox-emacs-d (expand-file-name "emacs" dropbox-d))
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "config.org" dropbox-emacs-d))
```

In config.org I have, among other things:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(use-package perspective :load-path "packages/perspective"
  :bind-keymap ("C-ä" . perspective-map)
  :config
  (persp-mode))
#+END_SRC
```

When config.org is converted to config.el, config.el contains this:

```
(use-package perspective :load-path "packages/perspective"
  :bind-keymap ("C-Ã¤" . perspective-map)
  :config
  (persp-mode))
```

Does anyone know why this character conversion happen? Both init.el and config.org are saved in utf-8 format. I have also tried adding the code below before loading config.org, and I have tried it with both the org-mode version shipped with emacs and the latest org-mode version.

```
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Comment: When you open `config.el` in Emacs, what coding system does Emacs use to read it? Check the value of `buffer-file-coding-system` in that buffer.

Comment: @legoscia Emacs says: Its value is utf-8-dos
Local in buffer config.el; global value is utf-8

Comment: Just to double-check, what does it say about `config.org`?

Comment: @legoscia I think I've tried to change the encoding of the files (after I got the first error), however it says: Its value is utf-8-unix
Local in buffer config.org; global value is utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I should post this as an answer or not, but anyway here it goes:

Adding `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)` before calling `org-babel-load-file` was actually the solution. The problem was that `org-babel-load-file` doesn't convert the .org-file unless there has been changes to the .org-file. Thus the previous version of the converted .el-file (in my case config.el) was run, and this version already had the bad characters written to it.

Since I only made changes to my init.el while tinkering with this problem, config.org wasn't modified. By removing config.el (or making a change in config.org), a new version of config.el was generated, and `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)` made sure that the ÅÄÖ characters worked.

Comment: Definitely solved my problem. I even encoded my .org file to utf-8 and deleted the .el file, but Emacs was still creating the .el file in non-UTF-8.